# how can i send mail from web application

Tags: java, email, web-applications, jersey, port

hi i have web application java using jersey, i deployed my program with tomcat and connect to the mysql DB ... i have one class that charge to send mail to user.
on localhost the class work fine and the mails sent, but afer i deployed the program and uploaded to the server the mail doesnt send to the user...

this ihs the clas:

```
 public static boolean SendMail(String from, String password, String message, String to[]) {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < to.length; index++) {
            toAddress[index] = new InternetAddress(to[index]);
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < toAddress.length; index++) {
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[index]);
        }
        mimeMessage.setSubject("email From linkeride");
        mimeMessage.setText(message);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, password);
        transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        return true;

    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

i maybe some one can tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Is your host running a mail server? If you want to do some testing I know there is a way to pipe emails through your gmail account. As for a production rollout you'd need a mail server to connect to.

Comment: Might be the simple case that your server is not able to reach the SMTP server or some port is blocked.

Comment: Is there an error? Does your network require a gateway for such connection?

Comment: there is no error.. i looks like the browser try to do the operation ("think..")

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, this code works on one machine and not on another, it seems more like server configuration issue rather than programming.

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
```

Try enabling debug mode for SMTP, thus in logs you will get complete insight at what step exactly your mail sending is getting failed.

Comment: added to my code this is what i got from the browesr:

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:

Comment: i forgat to mention the server run on linux.. that can be the problem?

Comment: Seems like connection from your new server to gmail server is blocked by firewall on your server. Please try running it by disabling firewall or adding some exception rule for your application.

Comment: can be that the server is not support of sending mail? or block it?

Comment: this is my school server,  and this is my site : http://mobedu2.mtacloud.co.il:8080/linkeride

Comment: it has nothing to do with your server capability, actually error says that your application from your server is not able to connect to gmail server. However you mentioned that it was able to connect from some other machine which means something on your school server is blocking mail send request to reach gmail server. It would be firewall only. I believe you need to contact this server admin to unblock outgoing request. I think it that would be it.